# C# Dynamic control anchor falling out of form

Tags: c#, size, anchor

I have a dynamic added pageview that I'm defining anchors on like shown below

```
                RadPageView newPageview = new RadPageView() { Size = new Size(300, 300), Location = new Point(350, 0) };
                newPageview.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
                newPage.Controls.Add(newPageview);
```

The result of this is shown in the picture.

[image: Image link]

As you seen, the pageview size is too large, causing it to fall out of the form. I wonder what is causing this? and what the solution might be?

OBS: I made searched for this for hours without results.

Thanks in advance.